# Find most recent date in a table using HIVE

Tags: hive

I just need to make a simple query of a table on a MapR cluster in that I want to know what the date is of the most recent record in the table.  Dates are in a 'report_date' column in string format.  I tried the following query without success:

select max(report_date) from partition.table_name

I know the second part of the statement works.  Is there something wrong with the first part?

Thanks, 
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date column datatype is string hence the max function doesnt produce the output as desired.

for example : string column with values 1,2,3,4 and when you run max(column) you wont get the output as 4 , since max doesnt work on string datatype.

Try changing your datatype to DATE or TIMESTAMP , Which should work.

**OR**

if changing datatype is not possible then try,

1. If there is an auto incrementing ID column in the table or any column like so , then
2. select report_date from table_name order by ID desc.

This should provide you the max date sting.